# Threading a pair-wise comparison/change of elements in a vector in Rust

Tags: rust, thread-safety, threadpool, pairwise

Tried threading work on a vector that requires pair-wise comparison and adjustment of elements in the vector. Instead of using a nested loop, I generate a vector of id's (usize) that are paired off to avoid sending the same id to different threads.

To get around safety checks, I used unsafe code and pointer trickery. I did this because I could guarantee that I would never operate on the same element of my main vector in different threads, but the compiler still sees it as passing parts of a mutable vector to different threads and gives an error.

This compiles both with and without scoped_threadpool code, but the threaded version experiences a 50x slowdown rather than any kind of speedup.

Apologies for the long post. I cannot think of a way to minimize this further without some of the extra code to show aspects of the setup.

I have a vector of `N` structs with `N=1<<m` with each struct having a Vec of 10 floats representing the position, velocity, and acceleration of particles in 3D, with an extra float for an additional comparison. I always have a power of 2 for the number of particles overall. I need to do a pair-wise comparison of the position (floats 0-2) to update the acceleration (floats 6-8) in between particles.

Rather than doing this in a nested loop, I set up a function (called, `get_ijpairs_vec`, shown at the end of this post) that returns a `Vec<usize>` with unique, non-overlapping pairs that span the entire range of points. There will be `N-1` such vectors to cycle through. I did this rather than using a nested loop because trying to grind a nested loop through a threadpool seems to be a messy problem based on other posts that I've read here.

My hope was that by generating a sequence of vectors that would guarantee that no races can occur, then I would be able to thread this ... but since I am sending two elements of my big vector at scoped_threadpool, it still doesn't like it. So, I made my first attempt at `unsafe` code to get around the problem by recasting pointers to the coordinate vector as usize, passing those into the scope of the threadpool, and then recasting once inside the threadpool. This worked, but is more than 10x slower (I'm guessing unsafe doesn't get optimized?) rather than 8x faster. Is there anything that can be done to leverage threading in this case.

For the example below, the `Mol` struct has a vector called `phase: Vec!<f64>=vec![0.0f64: 10]` that is set to a randomized set of initial conditions. The 'GasBox' struct contains a vector called `molecules: Vec!<Mol>` with `N=1<<m` elements and a field `nmol: usize` to remember `N`.

The function to return a vector of unique pairs of elements (or id's for elements) in the vector of `Mol`'s is

```
pub fn get_ijpairs_vec ( //in impl GasBox
  &self, //GasBox
  segment: usize, //there are N-1 possible vectors, pick one.
  result: &mut Vec<usize>, //where to build the vector.
) {
  let maxblock = self.nmol/2 ;
  let shift: usize = segment/2 + 1 ;
  let block: usize = 1<<(shift.trailing_zeros()) as usize ;
  let nblock = maxblock/block ;
  let skip = usize = if segment.trailing_zeros() > 0 { 0 } else { block } ;
  let needed: usize = (self.nmol as isize - result.capacity() as isize) as usize ;
  if needed > 0 { result.extend(vec![0usize; needed]) } ;
  let mut k: usize = 0 ;
  let mut i: usize = skip ;
  for _b in 0..nblock{
    for _c in 0..block {
      let mut j: usize = i + shift ;
      if j >= self.nmol {
        j -= self.nmol ;
        result[2*k] = j ;
        result[2*k+1] = i ;
      } else {
        result[2*k] = i ;
        result[2*k+1] = j ;
      }
      i += 1 ;
      k += 1 ;
      if i >= self.nmol { i -= self.nmol ; }
    }
    i += block ;
    if i >= self.nmol { i -= self.nmol ; }
  }
}
```

That gives me a vector of `N` `usize` elements, with each pair of elements giving unique id's for elements in the vector of `Mol` elements and no two pairs sharing a common id. I then feed this into another function:

```
pub fn update_accelerations( //in impl GasBox
  &mut self, //GasBox
) {
  let mut pairs: Vec<usize> = Vec::new() ;
  for i in (0..).take(self.nmol) {
    self.molecules[i].zero_accel() ; //sets elements 6-8 of phase to 0.0.
  }
  for k in (0..).take(self.nmol-1) { //N-1 possible vectors of pairs
    self.get_ijpairs_vec(k, &mut pairs) ;
//      self.pool.scoped(|scope|{
        for chunk in pairs.chunks_exact_mut(2) {
          let iptr: usize = self.molecules[chunk[0]].phase.as_ptr() as usize ;
          let jptr: usize = self.molecules[chunk[1]].phase.as_ptr() as usize ;
//          scope.execute(move || {
              GasBox::fix_accel(iptr, jptr) ;
//          } ) ;
        }
//    } ) ;
  }
}
```

The function fix_accel looks like

```
pub fn fix_accel(
  i: usize,
  j: usize,
) {
  let mut acc: Vec<f64> = vec![0.0f64; 3] ;
  unsafe {
    let iptr: *mut f64 = i as *mut f64 ;
    let jptr: *mut f64 = j as *mut f64 ;
    let mut sep2: f64 = 0.0 ;
    for k in (0..).take(3) {
      let tmp: f64 = *iptr.offset(k) - *jptr.offset(k) ;
      sep2 += tmp*tmp ;
    }
    //do some math to set up acc based on sep2.
    for k in (0..).take(3) {
      let tmp = *iptr.offset(k) - *jptr.offset(k) ;
      *iptr.offset(k+6) -= tmp*acc[k] ;
      *jptr.offset(k+6) += tmp*acc[k] ;
    }
  } //end the unsafe block
}
```

The code compiles with and without the scoped_threadpool lines in `update_accelerations` commented out. In both cases it runs as desired. But with scoped_threadpool code active, it takes about 50x as long to execute on an 8 core machine. The unsafe pointer trickery is there to utilize the fact that I can generate an ordering of the id's for the molecules that uses every molecule and does not have id's shared between pairs. I think of the pairing system as a variation of chunks_mut that can guaranteed safety, so should be safe to feed into a threadpool, but it doesn't get past the safety checks, so I need to resort to trickery with pointers.

Am I still doing something unsafe (i.e., am I still open to a race condition)?

If I am as safe as I think I am, is there a way to get a performance boost from threading this?

Comment: Nit: if you always have 10 elements, it's better to use an array than a vector.

Comment: That change actually resulted in a 15-18 % decrease in run time, depending on the size of N (better for bigger N). At least with single thread. Thanks

Comment: Strange. Maybe cache problems. Try boxing it (`Box<[f64; 10]>`). It stores the data in another location, similar to `Vec`, but is thinner and optimizes better.